# Extending react prop-types validation with custom checking

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am trying to do propTypes validation for of the **array prop** within my component. My propTypes validation looks something like this

```
Foo.propTypes = {
 columns: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      identifier: PropTypes.string,
      displayName: PropTypes.string,
      type: PropTypes.string,
      align: PropTypes.oneOf(['right', 'left', 'center']),
      sort: PropTypes.bool
    })
  )
}
```

Now I want to extend this validation with custom validation, by validating that only one value within columns array for **sort** property should be `true`

One option I have is to write the custom validation for whole columns array which would do `PropTypes.arrayOf` and `PropTypes.shape` validations and then do `sort` validation and throw `error` or `null`

But I don't want to do rework and want to utilize the inbuilt `React.PropTypes` to do all the validation and then add my custom validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can utilize `PropTypes` package within custom validator as well. So solved my issue with following code

```
Foo.propTypes = {
 columns: function(propValue, key, componentName, location, propFullName) {
    PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        identifier: PropTypes.string,
        displayName: PropTypes.string,
        type: PropTypes.string,
        align: PropTypes.oneOf(['right', 'left', 'center']),
        sort: PropTypes.bool
      })
    );
    if (propValue.columns.filter(i => i.sort === true).length > 1) {
      return new Error(
        `Invalid prop ${propFullName} supplied to ${componentName}. Only single object can have sort value as true`
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

prop-types is for runtime type checking, what you are trying to accomplish falls outside of that realm and is more like data validation. I wouldn't recommend using prop-types for this, even if it were possible.

I especially would warn against this because prop-types only warns in development. If your data is invalid, I'd imagine you'd want more of a consequence than that, like unsetting sort from all but one column, or displaying something to your user.